# Python HTTP request timing out on AWS Lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, https, python-requests, timeout

The line

```
response = requests.get('https:://url_for_my_endpoint.com', verify=False)
```

times out in my AWS lambda. I can access other endpoints, e.g.

```
response = requests.get('https://www.google.com/')
```

My endpoint is also accessible when running the line from local.

When the timeout is set for 5-10 seconds it'll simply time out, but when set to 5 minutes, for instance, it'll hang for the 5 minutes, then log this error:

```
errorMessage": "HTTPSConnectionPool(host='my_host', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /endpointparams (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at address>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out'))
```

Could it be a problem with the way I've configured the lambda layer with the requests library?

Comment: You have two colons `https::` in your endpoint URL. Is that just a typo in the question? Where is your endpoint hosted/located?

Comment: yes, just a typo. The endpoint is hosted on Kong.